# How can i verify if a user has a password? Ruby On Rails/ Devise

Tags: ruby, devise

I need to verify if a user has a password set or no. If no, i'll activate a button to resend an invitation to set_password, else the button will be desabled.

Comment: I haven't worked with Devise but maybe you use the [.valid_password?(nil)](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#valid_password%3F-instance_method) method, passing in nil

Comment: doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Device stores password hashes in a database column named `encrypted_password` (see [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable)).

Therefore I would expect that you can check if a user has a password set or not by calling

```
user.encrypted_password.present?
```

Btw I am surprised that users in your application can even signup without a password. Perhaps it makes sense to enforce a password at signup?

Comment: For both user with password & user without password, user.encrypted_password.present? is true. The flow of this API: a super_user is logged in, the super user will see if he need to resend an email . He can resend the email only if the new_user has no password set yet.(new users are saved, but without a password , they'll recive an email to set password). Maybe Devise set a password when user is saved???